# c# Where can find System.Windows.Controls.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have problem with dll file and have  project which need this file System.Windows.Controls.dll for

```
listBox1.ItemsSource
```

error fix , and add  reference with this dll to fix error.
Where i can find this dll file?
Is there any download link ? Share please !
Thanks !

In "Add Reference" it doesn't exist !

Solution: http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/6/776875B7-AD81-44D4-AA47-648D1BCB097E/silverlight_sdk.exe

Comment: What type of project is it, a class library?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter c# Windows Forms App

Comment: There are a few ListBox clsses, this might be one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx  or this might be one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx  Depending on which one you need, you would want to add a reference to the respective assembly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That namespace is in the PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: Remember that DLL names and Assembly names do not need to align in C#/.NET ..

Answer (score 29):

Here are the steps:

1. Right click on `References` in the `Solutions Explorer` (Solutions explorer is on the right of your IDE)
2. Select `Add Reference`
3. In the window that opens, Select `Assemblies > Framework`
4. Check the `PresentationFramework` component box and click ok

Comment: In Visual studio 2012 search PresentationFramework in the Framework under Assemblies

Answer (score 10):

This should be in the PresentationFramework.dll but that control is in the System.Windows.Controls namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx

You can add it by going to your project, Right clicking on References > Add Reference > .Net Tab > And selecting this DLL

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the dll file by searching my computer for "System.Windows.Controls.dll". I found it under the following file location... "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.dll"

Hope this helps!