# Cannot Import System.Windows.Controls

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, import, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use `System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs`, but I cannot import `System.Windows.Controls`. When I try to add a reference, `System.Windows.Controls` is not one of the assemblies that I can select.

Does anyone know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: I believe you are working in Winforms?

Comment: You need to have dot net 4.5 installed on your machine.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: Wrong; WPF and `PresentationFramework.dll` have been around since .Net 3.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of. I think the question is already answered. thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678794/c-sharp-where-can-find-system-windows-controls-dll

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The accepted answer tells you the problem but does not tell you how to solve it.I'll just add this for future visitors.
To solve this problem, you need to add the reference to `PresentationFramework.dll`.

**1** Go to `Solutions Explorer` (it's on the right of your IDE) > Right click on `References`

[image]

**2** Select `Add Reference`

in the window that opens, look for `Presentation Framework`, check the box and click okay. That's all. This is the way to add references to your project.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

`System.Windows.Controls` is a *namespace* that contains classes defined in `PresentationFramework.dll`.

However, if you don't already have a reference to that assembly, you're probably doing something wrong.
Are you sure you're actually using WPF?

Comment: Yep I just had to add a reference to PresentationFramework. Why it wasn't already referenced, I have no idea. Thank you!

Comment: @MageWind: If it wasn't already referenced, you probably aren't actually using WPF.

Comment: It is always good to add to your answer, how to do that. thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678794/c-sharp-where-can-find-system-windows-controls-dll

Comment: why is it important to use only WPF?