# How do I play multiple sounds at once? VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to play multiple sounds at once.
I have tried:

```
Private Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" _
(ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, _
ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer

'The Sub i am wanting to play the sound in
    mciSendString("close myWAV", Nothing, 0, 0)
    Dim fileName1 As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "\Sound\Sound file1.wav"
    mciSendString(String.Format("open ""{0}"" type mpegvideo alias myWAV", fileName1), Nothing, 0, 0)
    mciSendString("play myWAV", Nothing, 0, 0)
```

This does nothing at all, is it wrong?
I have also tried:

```
Dim SoundPlayer(2) As System.Media.SoundPlayer
SoundPlayer(1) = New Media.SoundPlayer(My.Resources.Sound_File_1)
SoundPlayer(2) = New Media.SoundPlayer(My.Resources.Sound_File_2)
SoundPlayer(1).Play
SoundPlayer(2).Play
```

This plays the second sound but not the first, so it plays sound 1 and then plays sound 2 but does it so fast you dont hear sound 1. So that doesn't work. I have also tried;

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Sound_File_1, AudioPlayMode.Background)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Sound_File_2, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

That does the same as my previous attempt... I have also tried using directX, but this wouldn't work...

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound
```

And directX seems a bit overboard for just trying to play 2 or 3 sounds at once.

I have also tried NAudio, which @Jeremy Thompson recomended (https://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio), I conveted it from C# to VB, using https://converter.telerik.com/ But it's not happy with a few parts of the code and i dont know why, here it is:

```
Public Class LoopStream
Inherits WaveStream

Private sourceStream As WaveStream

Public Sub New(ByVal sourceStream As WaveStream)
    Me.sourceStream = sourceStream
    Me.EnableLooping = True
End Sub

Public Property EnableLooping As Boolean

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property WaveFormat As WaveFormat
    Get
        Return sourceStream.WaveFormat
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Length As Long
    Get
        Return sourceStream.Length
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Property Position As Long
    Get
        Return sourceStream.Position
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        sourceStream.Position = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Overrides Function Read(ByVal buffer As Byte(), ByVal offset As Integer, ByVal count As Integer) As Integer
    Dim totalBytesRead As Integer = 0

    While totalBytesRead < count
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = sourceStream.Read(buffer, offset + totalBytesRead, count - totalBytesRead)

        If bytesRead = 0 Then

            If sourceStream.Position = 0 OrElse Not EnableLooping Then
                Exit While
            End If

            sourceStream.Position = 0
        End If

        totalBytesRead += bytesRead
    End While

    Return totalBytesRead
End Function
End Class
```

I have also tried this, but "System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement()" Doesnt exist?

```
Dim m1 As New System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement()
Dim m2 As New System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement()

m1.Source = New Uri(filename1)
m2.Source = New Uri(filename2)

m1.Play()
m2.Play()
```

Am i doing something wrong with one or more of these methods, or is their a different way to do it that i haven't tried?

Comment: Most people resort to NAudio: https://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio

Comment: @JeremyThompson I had a look at it, but i dont really understand it, how would i impliment it into my code?

Comment: You only spent 7 mins maximum looking at it! There's a point where if you're given documentation then you should be able to follow along, do more research to clarify and/or at least google some tutorials.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, That may be the case but I have spent 10+ hours trying to solve my issue with sound, and so far I have gotten nowhere. I'm sure there is a 100 different ways I could solve this, but im sick of looking into and trying to work it out, iv'e given up on that. It's obviously not working for me. The reason I have sent this question is I really just want an answer that i can impliment within 15m without having to do a bunch of research.

Comment: Well download this and run it through ILSpy to convert it to VB.Net https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4smnk0o1qcvndv/MusicToCodeByRemixed.zip?dl=0

Comment: @JeremyThompson I've never used IlSpy before, so i got it and tried to work out how to use it, I opened the files in the folder from that link and they all said this "// This file does not contain a managed assembly."

Comment: With regards to your NAudio edit, this is C# code: `public class LoopStream : WaveStream`. The VB equivalent would have `Inherits WaveStream` on the line under the class declaration.

Comment: @jmcilhinney. Oh, that would be a problem :D. So that means all of the code here markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio will be C#, dammit.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to convert anything. You can add a C# library project to your existing solution and reference that in your VB application project without issue. You can also reference built assemblies that were written in C#. The vast majority of the .NET BCL that already use was written in C#.

Comment: If you do want to convert, I suggest Instant VB from Tangible Software Solutions. The free version has some limitations but it is easily the best converter I've encountered.

Comment: To convert c# to vb => https://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: The posted code looks like it would be trivial to convert to VB by hand.  It's not doing anything remotely challenging.  I'd recommend having a working knowledge of C#, even if it isn't your preferred language, because you'll find that a lot of resources on .NET will only give examples in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the MediaElement

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement

it is Easy to use:

```
 Dim m1 As New System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement()
 Dim m2 As New System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement()

 m1.Source = New Uri(filename1)
 m2.Source = New Uri(filename2)

 m1.Play()
 m2.Play()
```

**Update**:

If you use .NET Framework <= 4.8 => [Cannot Import System.Windows.Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835507/cannot-import-system-windows-controls#answer-31474553)

If you use .NET CORE you have to add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` to your .csproj - file

[image]

Comment: according to my program "System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement()" doesn't exist, is this C# code?

Comment: If you use .NET Framework <= 4.8 => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835507/cannot-import-system-windows-controls#answer-31474553

Comment: If you use .NET CORE you have to add <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> to your .csproj - file

Comment: I was able to add the "Presentation Framwork"... But I dont know where my ".csprog" file is and I tried the code again and it still doesnt work... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What Project Type do you use?

Comment: Whats a project type?